# How jelastic control new installed program and make them persistant?

Tags: jelastic

As I know `jelastic` use `kubernetes`. I install sth with pip in python and then restart the pod but after reboot the newpackage that I install in pod exists but kubernetes can not handle it If I do this in kubernetes after reboot the new packages was deleted. and when I run `lsblk` in container I can see that my `/` is mounted but in kubernetes it is impossible.

is jelastic use kubernetes? If yes how can it handle new packages that user installed and mount `/`

Answer (score 1):

Jelastic is not based on K8s, but it has K8s as a package in Marketplace. Both cases you described above are possible in both Jelastic and Kubernetes. 
Simple restart of container will not erase the packages that were installed by the user, but reschedule (K8s) or redeploy (Jelastic) will.
Please use [Redeploy](https://docs.jelastic.com/container-redeploy) option from the dashboard or [this API](https://docs.jelastic.com/container-redeploy#api) call.

Comment: I test "Simple restart of container will not erase the packages"   alot and the new packages always deleted.